# Python: How to get every combination in list

Tags: python, list, combinations, permutation

I have a large amount of lists of lists. Here are only a few:

```
L1=(['G', 'C', 'A'], ['T', 'C'], ['T', 'C'])
L2=(['T', 'C'], ['T', 'C'], ['T', 'C'])
```

I need to get lists like this: (So basically every repeat from list to list)

```
L1=['GTT','CTT','ATT','GCC','CCC','ACC','GTC','CTC','ATC','GCT','CCT','ACT']
L2=['TTT','CTT','TCC','CCC','TCT','CTC','TTC','CCT']
```

Comment: In the first example, `'CCT', 'GCT', 'ACT'` are missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> [''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(*L1)]
['GTT', 'GTC', 'GCT', 'GCC', 'CTT', 'CTC', 'CCT', 'CCC', 'ATT', 'ATC', 'ACT', 'ACC']
>>>
>>> [''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(*L2)]
['TTT', 'TTC', 'TCT', 'TCC', 'CTT', 'CTC', 'CCT', 'CCC']
```

From the docs:

> Equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example, product(A, B) returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in B).

But we're using * argument unpacked argument of L1 for A, B, C, D...

Answer (score 3):

Use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> L1=(['G', 'C', 'A'], ['T', 'C'], ['T', 'C'])
>>> L2=(['T', 'C'], ['T', 'C'], ['T', 'C'])
>>>
>>> import itertools
>>>
>>> [''.join(xs) for xs in itertools.product(*L1)]
['GTT', 'GTC', 'GCT', 'GCC', 'CTT', 'CTC', 'CCT', 'CCC', 'ATT', 'ATC', 'ACT', 'ACC']
>>> [''.join(xs) for xs in itertools.product(*L2)]
['TTT', 'TTC', 'TCT', 'TCC', 'CTT', 'CTC', 'CCT', 'CCC']
```